# connection error with svnsync during SSL communication

Tags: svn, ssl, https, svnsync

I am on a Windows Server machine and trying to make a mirror of an SVN repository using `svnsync` (version 1.8.1 for win32, not installed, just extracted and `svnsync` called straight from the bin folder). The server requires a client certificate to grant access (https).

The messages I get from `svnsync` are

1. `E120171: Unable to connect to a repository at URL https://external.svnserver.com/myrepos`
2. `E120171: An error occurred during SSL communication`.

I can check out the repository via TortoiseSVN, providing my certificate as pfx-file.

I assume I have to provide the certificate for the svnsync command as well. Question is how? Or are there other options to mirror an svn repository?

Comment: What version of svnsync are you using and do you get the error immediately or does it happen part way through a sync?

Comment: I put more details into the question. I use version 1.8.1 and the error appears after about 2 seconds running `svnsync init`, no data transferred.

Comment: Log into the server, do a checkout - just so it asks you for a certificate - accept the certificate, then go back to the machine you were working on and try running the command with the `--trust-server-cert` option

Comment: @SameerSingh thanks for the suggestion, it didn't worked though - isn't it that I have to present my certificate to the server such that it grants access (rather than the other way around)?